# Java's equivalence to Python's "Got value: %s" % variable?

Tags: java, python, string, formatting

Java's equivalence to Python's "Got value: %s" % variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String.format("Got value: %s", variable);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.format("%s", aString)
```

See [Format](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) and all its various incarnations.

Comment: Your URL is faulty: http://file///opt/java/javase/jdk1.6/docs/api/java/text/Format.html